# how to check the new added record values to BindingSource

Tags: c#, sql, database, ado.net, bindingsource

how to check the new added record values to BindingSource before I save it to the database in C# ?

I want to create a method that checks the values in the Added row in the bindingsource and update some values then update the datasource

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution

```
        DataRowView dataRowView = (DataRowView)bindingSource.Current;

        if (dataRowView.IsNew)
        {

            dataRowView[2] = NewValue; // change values 
            // but why here I cannot get the column by name like dataRowView["ID"] it returns DbNull 
        }

        BindingSource.EndEdit();
```

Comment: why I cannot do like this dataRowView["ColumnName"] it returns DbNull